# Java: prevent another thread getting control until a specific command in the first thread is executed

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple concurrent code that increments a shared variable.

Two threads increment the counter 10,000,000 times each and print the result.

It works alright (race condition is resolved with `synchronized` inside the increment method).

However after thread A is done incrementing, thread B starts incrementing before thread A has a chance to prints its result (should be 10,000,000). I can resolve it by getting thread B to sleep 3 seconds before starting its own increment:

```
public class DogLatch {
    private static Counter counter = new Counter();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread a = new Thread(new A());
        Thread b = new Thread(new B());

        a.start();
        b.start();

        a.join();
        b.join();

        System.out.printf("counter: %,d", counter.getValue());
    }

    static class Counter  {
        private int i;

        public void increment()  {
            synchronized (this)  {
                i++;
            }
        }

        public int getValue()  {return i;}

        public void setValue(int i ) {this.i = i;}
    }

    static class A implements Runnable  {
        @Override
        public void run()  {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
                counter.increment();
            }

            System.out.println("A done: " + counter.getValue());
        }
    }

    static class B implements Runnable  {
        @Override
        public void run()  {
            System.out.println("Go to school");
            System.out.println("Walk dog");

            try  {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
                counter.increment();
            }

            System.out.println("B done: " + counter.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

would print

```
Go to school
Walk dog
A done: 10000000
B done: 20000000
counter: 20,000,000
```

However if I repalce `B` with:

```
static class B implements Runnable  {
        @Override
        public void run()  {
            System.out.println("Go to school");
            System.out.println("Walk dog");

            for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
                counter.increment();
            }

            System.out.println("B done: " + counter.getValue());
        }
    }
```

I get

```
Go to school
Walk dog
A done: 17368068
B done: 20000000
counter: 20,000,000
```

output. Is there a way to achieve the correct output where `A done: 10000000` and `B done: 10000000` is displayed, without resorting to `Thread.sleep()` in `B`?

Comment: You could use a [Synchronizer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) such as a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) or [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Comment: Re, "is there a way to achieve the correct output...?" The _best_ way to get the output that you want is to _not use threads._ The whole point of using threads is to let two or more things happen _concurrently_. That means, no definite time-ordered relationship between at least some of the things that happen in the different threads. In fact, the fewer times there are when two threads need to "sync up" with each other, the more likely you will benefit from using threads.  If everything your threads do has to be in lock step, then you're better off not using threads at all.

Comment: @besmirched I see your point. But I'm using such examples just to understand better the concepts & practice

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your program is not really doing much concurrent processing.  You wait 5 seconds in thread B while thread A increments up to 10,000,000 and then B wakes up and continues.

This would be the result if you just started them one after the other in a single thread.

But you know it's working fine since the the end result is always 20,000,000 without the sleep statement.

If you force alternation you will loose the benefit of using threads.  The fact that A prints out different values but the final tally is 20,000,000 is indicative of it working perfectly!